# Equations show in menu MATLAB

Tags: matlab, menu, equation

I'm having trouble printing a mathematical equation in menu.

Here's my code:

```
    choice = menu("I want to print equation here", 'Plot trajectory', 
   'Calculate acceleration');
```

And these are the equations that I would like to print:

```
x = 3*t - t^3
y = 4*t^2
```

Any idea how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: But you don’t want to use the string `'x = 3*t - t^3'`? Do you mean you want to show a LaTeX formatted string? Do you mean you want to show an image? Please clarify what the question really is.

Answer (score 1):

## Displaying Equations in MATLAB Menus

[image: Equations in Menu Dialogs]

### Method 1: Using Unicode Variations

Not the best or most reproducible way of doing it but pasting the superscripts directly into the string works to write the equations in the menu dialog. For a line break, the term `newline` can be concatenated between the two strings.

```
choice = menu(("x = 3t - t³" + newline + "y = 4t²"), 'Plot trajectory','Calculate acceleration');
```

---

### Method 2: Keeping Operators Symbolic Representations

An alternative way to create a line break is to use the `\n` term and to parse the data as a string using `sprint()`

```
choice = menu(sprintf("x = 3*t - t^3\ny = 4*t^2"), 'Plot trajectory','Calculate acceleration');
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**